# How to use nullable bool

Tags: c#

Why isn't this working?

```
bool? value = (1==2 ? true : null);
```

This works just fine:

```
bool? value = null;
```

or

```
bool? value = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a ternary operator, both sides of the colon have to be the same type:

```
var value = (1 == 2 ? true : (bool?)null);
```

This only applies to value types, since a value type cannot be implicitly converted to null (hence the need for nullable bool, nullable int, etc).

```
int groupId = (userId == 7) ? 5 : null;                  // invalid

int groupId = (userId == 7) ? 5 : (int)null;             // valid
```

It's okay to use `null` by itself on the other side of a reference type, which *can* be null:

```
string name = (userId == 7) ? "Bob" : null;              // valid

MyClass myClass = (userId == 7) ? new MyClass() : null;  // valid
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly cast on of the return type to `bool?` like:

```
bool? value = (1 == 2 ? (bool?)true : null);
```

Or

```
bool? value = (1 == 2 ? true : (bool?)null);
```

See [Conditional Operator C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Since there is no implicit conversion available between `bool` *(true)* and `null`, you get the error.